# How about creating a tag for Powershell JEA (Just Enough Administration)?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Thanks to this community, I just learned about Powershell JEA (Just Enough Administration).  It's an interesting technology that seems to fit right in to this community.  Any thoughts on the creation of `Powershell-JEA` tag?

Answer (score 3):

I've created the tag [powershell-jea](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/powershell-jea) by adding it to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/926870/powershell-jea-roledefinitions-trusted-domain).

If you have enough reputation for this, feel free to propose edits to the tag wiki.

Comment: Thanks!  Doesn't look like I have enough rep.